Copying Script to another gameobject in Unity
I am trying to completely copy (public + protected + private variables) one of my scripts to another gameobject at runtime, but the scripts have an abstract parent type and I refer to them during the script as the abstract parent type rather than the child classes as it could be any child, is there a way to do this? or maybe a more efficient way to go about doing this? I am trying to do this to have previews of turrets on my ship be shown - each ship can have multiple turret scripts, but during one of the menus I loop through all of them and am trying to copy them to a PreviewShip gameobject that then will be shown.
I have the following scripts hierarchy:
TurretController (abstract parent) -> (Children implemented scripts)Arc, Square, Single, Rows, Omni.
public void CopyTurret(GameObject turrets, TurretController turretToKeep)
{
    // REPLACE the current turrets with an instantiated copy of the turrets argument
    Destroy(transform.Find("Turrets").gameObject);
    Instantiate(original: turrets, parent: transform);
    /* go through all the turrets, and remove the ones that arent the turret name to 
    only get the specific turret on the ship */
    foreach (TurretController turret in GetComponentsInChildren<TurretController>())
        if (turret != turretToKeep)
            Destroy(turret);
}

This didn't work because I tried turretToKeep as TurretController (the abstract parent) and as a string (comparing script names) but both times the foreach loop ended up deleting every script rather than only keeping one.
public static void CopyComponent<T>(this Component comp, GameObject destination, bool copyVariables) where T : Component
{
    destination.AddComponent(typeof(T));
}

I also tried this extension method, but that copied the base version of the script rather than the updated version( updated variables ) that exists on the ship during runtime.

It's hard to tell what exactly your method is supposed to do .. could you show us some context? Like what is present on the object this component is attached to (since you are looking for child components on it)? What exactly is the structure of the thing you clone? And what exactly is the Find("Turrets") for? What exactly is the turretToKeep? I somewhat assume it is a previous existing turret you already destroyed as part of the Destroy(transform.Find("Turrets")); thing ... of course it is not part of the newly instantiated clone ...

Of course if you use AddComponent it means at a new instance of the component with the default values .. you want to use Instantiate for the deep clone ..
